# For area coordinates (latitude and longitude) in android

Tags: android, coordinates

There are N coordinates (latitude and longitude). Now I want to calculate the coordinates X and Y (latitude and longitude) less than radius X. What coordinates (latitude and longitude) point have in this N coordinates?

I have two points to know:

1. How to calculate the two coordinates (latitude and longitude) distance?
2. When calculate the coordinate everytime. Should it ergodic the N coordinates and  calculate  a distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can calculate the distance, in meters, between two latitude and longitude coordinates using the distanceBetween static method of the Location class:

```
import android.Location;

float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(xLatitude, xLongitude, yLatitude, yLongitude, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0];
```

As for your second question, I don't understand it as it is written now. Can you please edit your question and rewrite it?